# Installing Java 1.5 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, java, package-management

I already have Java 1.6, but I need to test something with 1.5.

I have downloaded the .bin file from http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index_jdk5.jsp using the Sun Download Manager.

Now I want to create a deb file from this bin file:

```
$ fakeroot make-jpkg java_ee_sdk-5_01-linux.bin
Creating temporary directory: /tmp/make-jpkg.Zpm1Y7LbZ0
Loading plugins: blackdown-j2re.sh blackdown-j2sdk.sh common.sh ibm-j2re.sh ibm-j2sdk.sh j2re.sh j2sdk-doc.sh j2sdk.sh j2se.sh sun-j2re.sh sun-j2sdk-doc.sh sun-j2sdk.sh

Detected Debian build architecture: i386
Detected Debian GNU type: i486-linux-gnu

No matching plugin was found.
Removing temporary directory: done
```

How can I fix the "No matching plugin was found." error?

#### Update

I downloaded `jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-amd64.bin` from the [archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html) page and ran Linux installer.

It works fine.

Comment: What are you wanting to test?

Comment: I'm experiencing this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689691/hudson-plugin-java-error-disagree-on-innerclasses-attribute. I wanted to try it out on an older Java version.

Comment: Why don't you use the java5 packages available for Ubuntu?

Comment: This issue with adding Java 5 to more recent versions of Ubuntu is a problem for those of us who want to contribute to the Android source code (http://source.android.com/source/download.html).  Android source can't use Java 6 "because of incompatibilities with @Override"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu version 9.04 or earlier, you can install the *sun-java5-jdk package*.

```
apt-get install sun-java5-jdk
```

If you are using version 9.10 or later you may be out of luck as the package is no longer supported. You could install Ubuntu 9.04 in a virtual machine or try a workaround in one of the solutions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/60132/jdk-install-no-matching-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Simply executing the .bin file and updating your `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables might work, depending on how your application accesses Java. You might also need to update the `java`, `javac`, etc. symlinks in `/usr/bin/` if your application uses them directly.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add hardy-update repository and install [package sun-java5-jre](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy-updates/sun-java5-jre). Here are [instructions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy-updates/all/sun-java5-jre/download).

Don't do any upgrades. Disable that repository after you install sun-java5-jre.

Note, that this package is in both `hardy` and **`hardy-updates`** repositories, but you want the one from hardy-updates (it has important fixes).

Also note, that hardy (server) release is the only still supported release which has java5 package.